# Android: method don't executes in a loop Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a app(client) that establish a connection with a server and i'm trying send a specific command string to this app(client) and this command is received on client with sucess, but only after a "interruption" on Thread like for example: when close server or when breaks this loop Thread.

So, my goal is make this specific command string be received normaly inside Thread without any kind of "interruption" for outside of Thread.

Any suggestion are welcome.

***Android code***

```
    class CommsThread implements Runnable {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try {

                    while(clientSocket.isConnected() && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){

                        //System.out.println("Waiting for server request");

                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

                        String message = reader.readLine();

                        if(message != null && !message.trim().isEmpty()) {


// Don't executes on moment that i send, only after of a "interruption" in this Thread

                        System.out.println("Message Received: " + message); 

                       // Specific command string here to execute a foo() method

                        if(message.equalsIgnoreCase("foo")){

                            // foo();
                        }

 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                        }

                        reader.close();

                        //clientSocket.close();

                        if(message.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) break;

                         Thread.sleep(100);
                    }
                    System.out.println("Shutting down Socket!!");
                    clientSocket.close();
                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        //Log.e("clients", e1.toString());
                        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e1.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        System.out.println(e1.toString());
                    } 

                }

                }
```

Comment: `String message = reader.readLine();`. So your client tries to read a line! A line is a series of characters ending with "\n". Sadly we cannot see what your server is sending.

Comment: @greenapps, my server sends the "foo" string, like i'm showing above :-)

Comment: So your server is sending a string and your client is trying to read a line. You did not grab the point i believe.

Comment: So, what you suggest for solve this trouble my friend? :-)

Comment: Im not your friend and you can stop with those `;-)` as i find them not appropriate. If you would show that you understood the problem that i explained  then we could go on. But you are not showing that you understand.

Comment: :D, :D, :D, :D, :D, :D

Comment: @greenapps, `Sadly we cannot see what your server is sending.` But i already said that server sends "any thing without \n" to client side. You still not understood it? :D